# Git log pretty does not show yellow color on Windows

Tags: git, powershell

I use PowerShell with posh-git. According to 
https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/git-advanced-tips-tricks/table-of-contents the following command line

```
git log --pretty='%Cred%h%Creset | %C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset %C(cyan)[%an]%Creset'
```

should display the branch reference in yellow. However, it does not work:

[image]

The red, green and cyan do show up, but not the yellow, which should color the string `(HEAD -> master, origin/master)`. I checked and it does not work if I try to use yellow for other parts of the log too. It is as if PowerShell is unable to render yellow.

Here is the snapshot from the PluralSight video:

[image]

In the snapshot the shell is zsh and the OS is Unix or Linux, but I do not see any reason why PowerShell should not be able to display yellow.

What is wrong?

Comment: I tried this with " " around this "%Cred%h%Creset | %C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset %C(cyan)[%an]%Creset" and I think I see yellow that you want

Comment: Do you mean like this `git log --pretty="%Cred%h%Creset | %C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset %C(cyan)[%an]%Creset" --graph`? If so, I still cannot see yellow.

Comment: yes that is what I tried and it appeared to be yellow for me.

Comment: You have just confirmed I have a problem. The question is why and how to solve it?

Comment: did you forget the --graph on your first post?

Comment: I did, but it does not matter. The result is the same with or without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed all my issues with Powershell colors using the following script.

**FixPowershellColors.ps1**

```
reg import $PSScriptRoot\Windows10ConsoleColors.reg
$WindowsPowerShellShortcutDir = "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell"
$UserPinnedTaskBarDir = "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar"
$sh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
@(
    "Windows PowerShell",
    "Windows PowerShell (x86)",
    "Windows PowerShell ISE",
    "Windows PowerShell ISE (x86)"
) |% {
    $ShortcutName = $_
    @(
        "$WindowsPowerShellShortcutDir",
        "$UserPinnedTaskBarDir"
    ) |? { Test-Path "$_\$ShortcutName.lnk" } |% {
        $ShortcutPath = "$_\$ShortcutName.lnk"
        $Shortcut = $sh.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
        $TargetPath = $Shortcut.TargetPath
        del $ShortcutPath
        $Shortcut = $sh.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
        $Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetPath
        $Shortcut.Save()
    }
}
"Reopen PowerShell console to see the changes"
```

It takes the first line to update the Powershell colors from `Windows10ConsoleColors.reg` and the rest is dedicated to refreshing the various Powershell shortcuts.

**Windows10ConsoleColors.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"ColorTable00"=dword:000c0c0c
"ColorTable01"=dword:00c50f1f
"ColorTable02"=dword:0013a10e
"ColorTable03"=dword:00c19c00
"ColorTable04"=dword:000037da
"ColorTable05"=dword:00881798
"ColorTable06"=dword:003a96dd
"ColorTable07"=dword:00cccccc
"ColorTable08"=dword:00767676
"ColorTable09"=dword:00e74860
"ColorTable10"=dword:0016c60c
"ColorTable11"=dword:00f9f1a5
"ColorTable12"=dword:003b78ff
"ColorTable13"=dword:00b4009e
"ColorTable14"=dword:0061d6d6
"ColorTable15"=dword:00f2f2f2
```

So, as long as your powershell shortcuts are in the well-known locations the script updates them all after which you just need to reopen the console window.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, and i switched to using bold colors which worked for me.

try this (i also changed red to bold as it is more visible that way):

`git log --pretty="%C(red bold)%h%Creset | %C(yellow bold)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset %C(cyan)[%an]%Creset"`